# How to get cell info and connected towers info?

Tags: android, networking, telecommunication

I want to collect information of sim card cell info and the info of the connected towers like power info Tx, Rx, MsTx,LAC and so on.

As shown in the picture below of service mode in sanding

[image]

I would like any sdks, codes or marinating formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at `android.telephony.NeighboringCellInfo`, it should help.

Link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/NeighboringCellInfo

Comment: Thanx for your time, but I want data like tower Rx and Tx
I can't seem to find them